# Sum of Gaussian binomial coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

We all know that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}=2^{n}$. Is there a similar result regarding the q-binomial coefficients? (a.k.a Gaussian binomial coefficients) - $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}_{q}=?$

Comment: I think that you need to define your normalizations before stating the question. What is your definition of $[n]_q?$

Answer (score 11):

The identity $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1+xq^i) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k
q^{{k\choose 2}}{n\choose k}_q$ is the $q$-*binomial theorem*. A
combinatorial proof based on integer partitions is mentioned on page
68 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, 2nd ed. There is also given
a combinatorial proof based on finite fields. For the online version
at http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf, see pages 74-75.

Comment: Is it the answer?

Answer (score 7):

There are many possibilities, e.g.
$\sum_{i=0}^{n}q^i{n \choose i}_{q^2}=(1+q)(1+q^2)...(1+q^n)$

or

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}q^{i(i+1)/2}{n \choose i}_{q
}=(1+q)(1+q^2)...(1+q^n).$

Comment: That's interesting.  Do you know a bijective proof of these identities, based on the fact that the Gaussian binomial coefficient is the number of subspaces of dimension $i$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/q)^n$?

Comment: I know no direct bijective proofs of this sort. The second identity can be deduced from a polynomial identity which has a bijective proof in the setting of finite vector spaces, cf. Goldman - Rota, Finite vector spaces and Eulerian generating functions, Studies in Appl. Math. XLIX (3), 1970.

Comment: The second one is the q-binomial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem evaluated at $t=q$. The first one is exercise 99 in the book "Integer Partitions" by Andrews and Eriksson, 2004, but no solution is given. Is there a similar conceptual approach?

Answer (score 7):

For Gaussian binomial coefficients we have
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^n  \binom nk_q = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty a_m q^m,
$$
where 
$$
a_m = \sum_{\lambda\vdash m} \#\{k\in \mathbf Z_{\geq 0}\mid \lambda_1\leq n-k, \lambda'_1\leq k\}.
$$
The notation $\lambda\vdash m$ signifies that $\lambda$ is an integer partition of $m$.
Also $\lambda_1$ is the first (largest) part of $\lambda$ and $\lambda'_1$ is the number of positive parts in $\lambda$.

This follows from the following well-known fact about Gaussian binomial coefficients:
$$
\binom nk_q = \sum_\lambda q^{|\lambda|}, 
$$
the sum being over all partitions $\lambda$ where $\lambda_1\leq n-k$ and $\lambda'_1\leq k$ (see, for example Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics, vol. 1*, or Eq. (4) in my expository article titled *[Counting subspaces in a Finite Vector Space](http://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/summaries.html#counting)*).

Answer (score 4):

One more version - analog of $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom ni=0$:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom ni_q=\begin{cases}0,&n=2k-1\\
\prod_{j=1}^k(1-q^{2j-1}),&n=2k\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Could you sketch a proof of this, or give a reference?

Comment: @aleph It was proved by Gauss in his "Summatio Quarumdam Serierum Singularium", section 6.  Here is a link: https://eudml.org/doc/203313.

Comment: @LucasCuller Many thanks for this reference!

Comment: A proof is found on pages 71/72 in the book "Integer Partitions" by Andrews and Eriksson, 2004. They call it the "Gaussian formula".